# Can you pack multiple native modules into the same NPM package?

Tags: node.js, npm, module

I've written a cross-platform [nodejs](https://nodejs.org) native module in [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) using [cmake](http://cmake.org/), [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/), plus a few abstractions and carefully placed [#ifdefs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html).

It is built into a module using [cmake-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cmake-js) and I have 3 build servers: `Windows`, `Mac` and `Linux` doing the buliding so I have 3 native modules that work fine on all the platforms.

We have an internal [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) repository that I could go ahead and publish to so that other teams within the company can simply `npm install module` to get my module.

The thing is, it's kind of messy that the client would need to pick a module based on the platform they're on (i.e. I would deploy all 3 modules from each of the build servers) so I would rather deploy a single module by somehow merging together the 3 platform specific modules.

**Is this possible and how do I structure the internals of such a module?***

Does, for example, [bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings) figure out the platform and find the appropriate `.node` file?

**I don't want to include the code and have the client compile it as that puts a pretty large burden on the client (they would be expecting to be able to write a simple script using Javascript, for example, and use my module - it would be a shock that they need to set up C build chains, worry about the platform their script is running on etc, etc, etc).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most simple solution that comes to my mind - if you packed your code into modules for different platforms then you've got package like:

- `fancy-module-linux`
- `fancy-module-windows`
- `fancy-module-mac`

You can also provide a *common module* let's say `fancy-module`.

In a most basic scenario:

`fancy-module` is an empty module with just a *README*

You provide custom `install` script in the `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "install": "node ./install_platform_dep.js"
  }
}
```

Then when installing `fancy-module` the `install_platform_dep.js`  script will be executed. Inside `install_platform_dep.js` you place:

```
// For Windows...
if(process.platform === 'win32') {
    // Trigger Windows module installation
    exec('npm install fancy-module-windows', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
         // Some error handling...
    }
} else if ... // Process other OS'es
```

You don't have to even publish anything separately! Alternatively you can just put everything into `fancy-module`:

```
package.json
README.md
src
  |- Windows
  |  # Here you've got just copied contents of `fancy-module-windows`
  |- Linux
  |  # This folder have same contents as `fancy-module-linux`
  \- Mac
     # Same
```

And do `exec('npm install ./src/Windows' /* ... */)`

And you get one nice single *multiplatform* bundle.

There's no other way to achieve multiplatform module than doing what I described.

Anyway it's rather ugly to provide *installer-like module just to install stuff* but afik that's the most straightforward option.

Many packages (built around Electron and paltform dependent stuff) on npm are just installers to install other packages, so it's a good way to go.

**Edit:**

For os detection you can use modules like: `is-linux` or `is-windows` etc. and not worry about `process.platform`

[Read more about is-linux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-linux)
[Read more about is-windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-windows)
[Read more about process.paltform](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform)
[Read more about install hook in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#special-packagejson-config-object)

**Edit #2**:

Alternatively you can use already made package `node-pre-gyp` as described here:

[Cross platform addon using node-pre-gyp](https://nodeaddons.com/cross-platform-addons-with-node-pre-gyp/)

This package does in reality something to the described approach.

Comment: This is great, thank you, Piotr, I am going to go with this scheme.

Comment: why not just make the 3 native modules dependencies of the parent module, and export the JS apis from the parent module. no special postinstall script needed.